# Lua unpack bug?

Tags: lua, unpack

I Have stumbled on a weird behavior in Lua unpack function

```
table1 = {true, nil, true, false, nil, true, nil}
table2 = {true, false, nil, false, nil, true, nil}

a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1 = unpack( table1 )
print ("table1:",a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1)

a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2 = unpack( table2 )
print ("table2:",a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2)
```

Output:

```
table1: true    nil true    false   nil nil nil
table2: true    false   nil nil nil nil nil
```

The second unpack delivers parameters up to the first nil value. I could live with that.
The first table delivers 4? parameters with one being nil in the middle. It has 4 parameters that are not nil, but they aren't the one that are shown.

Could anyone explain this? 
This was tried with codepad.org and lua 5.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem can be resolved simply by specifying the beginning and ending indexes to `unpack()` and using the `table.maxn()` as the ending index:

```
table1 = {true, nil, true, false, nil, true, nil}

a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1 = unpack( table1, 1, table.maxn(table1) )
print ("table1:",a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1)
-->table1: true    nil     true    false   nil     true    nil
```

The true reason for the discrepancy on how the two tables are handled is in the logic of determining the length of the array portion of the table.

The `luaB_unpack()` function uses `luaL_getn()` which is defined in terms of `lua_objlen()` which calls `luaH_getn()` for tables.  The `luaH_getn()` looks at the last position of the array, and if it is `nil` performs a binary search for a boundary in the table ("such that t[i] is non-nil and t[i+1] is nil").  The binary search for the end of the array is the reason that `table1` is handled differently then `table2`.

This should only be an issue if the last entry in the array is `nil`.

From [Programming in Lua](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/) (pg.16) (You should buy this book.):
*When an array has holes--nil elements inside it--the length operator may assume any of these nil elements as the end marker.  Therefore, you should avoid using the length operator on arrays that may contain holes.*

The `unpack()` is using the length operator `lua_objlen()`, which "may assume any of [the] nil elements as the end" of the array.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. Does this mean that table.maxn() traverses the whole allocated size for the table?

Comment: table.maxn() "Returns the largest positive numerical index of the given table" see http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.maxn

Comment: is table.maxn really guaranteed to return the correct value (= the number of objects in the table literal) here?

Comment: @kazer.se `table.maxn` will return `6` which is the largest index for the table `table1` with a non-nil entry.  The `nil` in the 7th position will not be counted by `table.maxn`; however, for this case it works perfectly.  The `unpack` will return 6 elements and the 7th variable being assigned will receive `nil` as "the list is extended with as many nil's as needed" for the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

[2.2 - Values and Types](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2)

> [...]
>   The type **table** implements associative
>   arrays, that is, arrays that can be
>   indexed not only with numbers, but
>   with any value (except nil). Tables
>   can be heterogeneous; that is, **they**
>   **can contain values of all types
>   (except nil)**. [...]

Given `nil` to an entry will *break* the table enumeration and your variables wont be init properly.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates a *problematic* behavior:

```
table1 = {true, false, nil, false, nil, true, nil}
for k,v in ipairs(table1) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

output:

```
1   true
2   false
>Exit code: 0
```

Comment: More specifically, i suspect that it ignores the `nil`s he specified.

Comment: No, it does not RCIX, in that case table 2 would have returned 4 values as well i guess.

Comment: The only reason that the for loop stopped is because the iterator returned nil at position 3.  The table was still initialized properly, because `assert(table1[1]==true and table1[2]==false and table1[3]==nil and table1[4]==false and table1[5]==nil and table1[6]==true and table1[7]==nil)` does not assert.

Comment: @gwell, I said that the `nil` can *break* the enumeration. I didn't say that the elements will cease to exist.