# Lua array as parameter with null

Tags: lua

I have a problem, i need to call a function with variable parameters that i get from a webservice... so for example:

I have a function:

```
function MyPrint(param1, param2)
   print(param1, param2)
end
```

I save this function in an array of callbacks:

```
callback[1] = MyPrint
```

I get parameters from server:

```
params = "[2, 88]" --> JSON from server
```

I do:

```
params = json.decode(params)
-- so 
-- params[1] = 2
-- params[2] = 88
```

I tried to pass this parameters to my callback as:

```
pcall(callback[1], unpack(params))
```

I got `2` and `88` on MyPrint function...

But if server sends `"[null, 88]"`, I got `nil` on both values... I have readed that `unpack` function has problem with null values... but then... how can I call `callback[1]` with some `null` values?

Is there a way to pass an array of parameters directly to function without unpack it?

EDIT: I created MyPrint as an example... but really I don't know how many params needs the callback function, i only have a list of functions and needs to call them with a variable number of parameters that i got from server.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/10UuPc6j -- works here. What's your lua version? What's the value of `params` before unpacking? Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672985/lua-unpack-bug)

Comment: `json.decode` should create additional field `n` in the table returned to store the number of arguments.  Then `your_function(unpack(params,1,params.n))` would solve the problem.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There is no "n" field... `print(params.n)` --> nil

Comment: @diego It seems the problem is on `json.decode` ignoring the null parameter thats why your example works... it pass the null directly without parsing the null with json.decode

Comment: If you can't make `json.decode` create a `n` field or equivalent then there is a loss of data. You can't very well deal of a json object without know how many elements there are. To move on,  you'll have to find a way to carry over the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a table has gaps, you should explicitly specify a range of indices to unpack: `table.unpack(params, 1, table.maxn(params))`. This works well in lua 5.1.5.