# Lua can't unpack a table starts with two nil assigned elementwise

Tags: lua, lua-table, unpack

I tried the following code in Lua. The first four cases work well but the last two fail. I get nil as results in those two. What is the problem?

```
v = {nil, 10, nil}
a, b, c = unpack(v)
-- Output: a, b, c =  nil 10  nil
print('a, b, c = ', a, b, c)

v = {nil, nil, 10}
a, b, c = unpack(v)
-- Output: a, b, c =  nil nil 10
print('a, b, c = ', a, b, c)

v = {}
v[2] = 10
a, b, c = unpack(v)
-- Output: a, b, c =  nil 10  nil 
print('a, b, c = ', a, b, c)

v = {}
v[1] = nil
v[2] = 10
v[3] = nil
a, b, c = unpack(v)
-- Output: a, b, c =  nil 10  nil
print('a, b, c = ', a, b, c)

v = {}
v[3] = 10
a, b, c = unpack(v)
-- Output: a, b, c =  nil nil nil
print('a, b, c = ', a, b, c)

v = {}
v[1] = nil
v[2] = nil
v[3] = 10
a, b, c = unpack(v)
-- Output: a, b, c =  nil nil nil
print('a, b, c = ', a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a table as an array, all elements are required to have values different than `nil`.

Setting the value for a key to `nil` effectively removes that key from the table. But in an array all integer keys from 1 to the length of that array must be set. “Holes” are not allowed. So the behaviour in *all your cases* is unspecified.

You can verify by printing all key/value pairs in the table:

```
t = {0, nil, 2, 3}

print("pairs:")
for k, v in pairs(t) do
    print("["..k.."]", v)
end
```

And note how `ipairs` breaks, since it stops at the first `nil` element.

```
print("ipairs:")
for k, v in ipairs(t) do
    print("["..k.."]", v)
end
```

Workaround in your case is described in an answer here: [Lua unpack bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672985/lua-unpack-bug)

Comment: That's why the manual doesn't use the term "array." It describes a table as having a "sequence" or not having a sequence. # (length) and ipairs work well on a sequence. (# isn't even deterministic on a non-sequence.)