# Lua: Unpack with nil? Alternative?

Tags: lua, love2d

I've run into the age old [unpack bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672985/lua-unpack-bug), where I have an array in Lua that can contain nil values, and I want to unpack the array with the nil values; which seems is not possible. What is the alternative to this logic?

Here is the code I am attempting to run

```
function InputSystem:poll(name, ...)
  local system = self:findComponent(name)
  local values, arr = {...}, {}
  for i, v in pairs(values) do
    arr[#arr+1] = system[v]
  end

  --If the first guy is null this does not work!! WHY
  return unpack(arr, 1, table.maxn(values))
end
```

The idea is I poll my input system dynamically so that I only return the values I want like so:

```
local dragged,clicked,scrolled = self.SystemManager:findSystem('Input'):poll('Mouse', 'Dragged', 'Clicked', 'Scrolled')
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

EDIT:

I seem to not understand Lua fully. I was wanting to return the same amount of variables as passed in by ..., but in the loop if the property is not found I thought it would set it to nil, but this seems to be wrong.

```
function InputSystem:poll(name, ...)
      local system = self:findComponent(name)
      local values, arr = {...}, {}
      for i, v in pairs(values) do
        arr[#arr+1] = system[v] --If not found set nil
      end

      --I want this to return the length of ... in variables
      --Example I pass 'Dragged', 'Clicked' I would want it to return nil {x:1,y:1}
      return unpack(arr, 1, table.maxn(values))
    end
```

Clearly I am a Lua master...

Comment: A function not being specified to do what you want doesn't make it buggy...

Comment: @Deduplicator I did't mean it like that, I was referencing a previous post with a the same issue. Its my logic that was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i, v in pairs(values) do
  arr[#arr+1] = system[v] -- This doesn't work!
end
```

The problem with your implementation is that you expect appending nil to an array to increase it's length, which it doesn't:

```
local arr = {1, 2, 3}
print(#arr) --> 3
arr[#arr+1]=nil
print(#arr) --> 3
```

What you want is, essentially, a `map` function, that takes a list of elements, applies a function `fn` to each of them and returns the list of the results.

Normally, this can easily be implemented as a [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) function like this:

```
local function map(fn, elem, ...)
  if elem then return fn(elem), map(fn, ...)
end
```

This doesn't deal well with `nil` arguments though, as they would make the condition false while there are still arguments left to handle, but we can modify it using `select` to avoid this:

```
local function map(fn, elem, ...)
  if select('#', ...)>0 then return fn(elem), map(fn, ...)
  else return fn(elem) end
end
-- This implementation still gets TCOd :)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
map(string.upper, 'hello', 'world') --> 'HELLO', 'WORLD'
```

You want to map each value in `...` to the corresponding value in a table, but since `map` takes a function as its first value, we can just wrap that in a function. And because the table isn't known to us at the time of writing the code, we have to generate the function at runtime:

```
local function index(table)
  return function(idx)
    return table[idx]
  end
end
```

Now we can do this:

```
map(index{'hello', 'world'}, 1, 2) --> 'hello', 'world'
-- index{'hello', 'world'} returns a function that indexes the given table
-- with its first argument and returns the value
```

Then you can write your `InputSystem` function like this:

```
function InputSystem:poll(name, ...)
  return map(index(self:findComponent(name)), ...)
end
```

Obviously, we don't need that generic map function in this case, since we're always indexing a table. We can rewrite map to use a table like this:

```
local function map(tab, elem, ...)
  if select('#', ...)>0 then return tab[elem], map(tab, ...)
  else return tab[elem] end
end
```

and the main function will become:

```
function InputSystem:poll(name, ...)
  return map(self:findComponent(name), ...)
end
```

One more thing I noticed:

```
  for i, v in pairs(values) do
    arr[#arr+1] = system[v] --If not found set nil
  end
```

`pairs` iterates out of order, so your line `for i, v in pairs(values) do` may very well completely re-order the values. Since further down you write `local dragged,clicked,scrolled = self.SystemManager:findSystem...` I believe you expect the return values to remain in order.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the answer! The biggest take away for me was I did not grasp the idea that appending nil to a table does not increase the index (which is probably obvious but I didn't get it.) So, the map goes through and recursively returns each property in the table. I had no idea you could do mult returns like that. Thanks again!

Comment: The map function is missing an end after the else clause, I tried to edit it and it wouldn't let me. Not sure if it matters, just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @GrizzlyEnglish Fixed it :)

Comment: Doesn't solve the actual specifically stated problem of `unpack` NotDoingTheRightThing™. Offers a workaround that is useless to most of those facing the problem AsStated®, and search-shadows potential solutions to it. Textbook example of the "XY problem problem".

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I agree that it was an XY question. OP wanted one thing, and asked another; I did my best at giving a solution to the *actual* problem.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer And this is precisely the problem with so-called "XY questions". Somebody asks question Y, but this question receives an answer to question X instead, and from that point on until forever the universe considers question Y satisfactorily answered even though it is not. The possibility of the actual question Y ever being answered falls beyond an event horizon and is lost forever. X answers DEVOUR Y questions. I didn't say "XY problem", I said "XY problem problem". It wasn't a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `table.pack` and `table.unpack` to preserve `nil`s.  If you use Lua 5.2 or above you can remove the compatibility snippet.

```
-- Backwards compatibility
table.pack = table.pack or function(...) return { n = select("#", ...), ... } end
table.unpack = table.unpack or unpack

function test(...)
    local values = table.pack(...)
    local arr = {}
    for i, v in pairs(values) do
        -- iterates only the non-nil fields of "values"
        arr[i] = 10*v
    end
    return table.unpack(arr, 1, values.n)
end

print(test(nil, 1, nil, 2, nil, nil, 3))
```

```
$ lua5.3 test.lua
nil 10  nil 20  nil nil 30
$ lua5.2 test.lua
nil 10  nil 20  nil nil 30
$ lua5.1 test.lua
nil 10  nil 20  nil nil 30
$ luajit test.lua
nil 10  nil 20  nil nil 30
```

Comment: @henri-menke Thanks for the reply! I seem to have not fully understood my issue, and edited my question.

Comment: @GrizzlyEnglish `arr[i] = system[v]`

Comment: @HenriMenke I wanted to point that out as well, but you'll notice `pairs` is used, not `ipairs`, thus the order is messed up anyway. Just changing it to `ipairs` is not an option, because that's only defined for sequences.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer No, the order is just fine. See the updated example in my answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke With your comment and DarkWiiPlayer I understand that me trying to increase the index does not work with nils. I marked DarkWiiPlayers answer 'cause it helped me understand a little better. But thank you for the help!

Comment: @HenriMenke If the values remain in order, that's coincidence. Probably because they are stored in the array part of the table. Whatever the reason, inserting and removing values later on may still mess up the order.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer No, it's not a coincidence.  The elements are stored and restored in order.  Look at the source of [`table.pack`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltablib.c.html#pack) and [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltablib.c.html#unpack) to convince yourself.

Comment: `table.pack` and `table.unpack` keep the order, yes. It's `pairs` that iterates out of order. Looking at your code again, it seems I overlooked that you changed `arr[#arr+1]` from the original to `arr[i]`, so the order of iteration actually doesn't matter at all. Either way `ipairs` is supposedly a bit faster, iirc.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer But `ipairs` won't work because the table has holes.